# Use Curl command send soap request return http 400

Tags: curl, soap

I could send soap request in postman successfully. Then I copy the curl command from postman, try it in curl on Windows. But it return http 400.

curl https://xxx   -H "cache-control: no-cache"   -H "content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"   -H "soapaction: Getxxxx"   -d "D:\request.xml" -v

If just try get, it return http 200.
curl https://xxx -v

Answer (score 0):

should use @ before file name like below:

curl https://xxx -H "cache-control: no-cache" -H "content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" -H "soapaction: Getxxxx" -d @D:\request.xml -v